# Building chrome extension to sort open tabs by DOM element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I am building a chrome extension. The goal is to sort all open tabs from youtube by video duration (low to high).

I found this code from this [GitHub project](https://github.com/andyhaskell/tab-sorter), explained in [this tutorial](https://dev.to/andyhaskell/build-your-first-chrome-extension-with-chrome-tabs-3625):

`popup.js`

```
function byAlphabeticalURLOrder(tab1, tab2) {
  if (tab1.url < tab2.url) {
    return -1;
  } else if (tab1.url > tab2.url) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

chrome.tabs.query({windowId: chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT}, (tabs) => {
  tabs.sort(byAlphabeticalURLOrder);
  for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    chrome.tabs.move(tabs[i].id, {index: i});
  }
});
```

This code works perfectly with sorting by alphabetical order. However, I want to adjust it to sort by video duration.

So I wrote this file to get video duration from all open tabs but still can't get around to the "sorting or moving tabs" part.

`popup.js`

```
chrome.tabs.query({
  windowId: chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT
}, (tabs) => {
  chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, {
        code: '(' + function () {
          return {
            seconds: document.querySelector("video").duration
          };
        } + ')()'
      }, function (result) {
        document.write(result[0].seconds + '<br>');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**Output (Video duration in seconds) - (Appears in `popup.html`):**

```
1229.041
187.501
510.581
609.941
1473.821
955.481
5464.281
59.201
1787.701
1523.941
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you've tried, but you can add those values to objects in array in your existing loop and then sort that array in a second loop. Because executeScript is asynchronous, you need to wait for the first loop to finish, which means resolving a list of promises, then sorting the list on videolength, then moving the tabs.

Here's what I came up with for MV3. There are probably cleaner ways to do this (I'm fairly new at this):

**Edits: Minor edits to cleaned up code organization. Attached function to action (I.e., runs on clicking Chrome extension icon button).*

**popup.js**

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(sortTabsbyDuration);

async function sortTabsbyDuration() {
  async function createListEntry(tabId, i) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      if (/\.youtube\.com\/watch\?/.test(tabs[i].url)) {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript(
          { target: { tabId: tabId }, func: getYouTubeLength, args: [tabId] },
          (returnValue) => {
            resolve(returnValue[0].result);
          }
        );
      } else {
        resolve({
          tabId: tabId,
          vidLength: 9999999999,
        });
      }
    });
  }
  function getYouTubeLength(aTab) {
    let vidLength = document.querySelector("video").duration;
    if (!vidLength) {
      vidLength=1;
    }
    return {
      tabId: aTab,
      vidLength: vidLength,
    };
  }
  // MAIN:
  const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true });
  let promiseList = [];
  for (var index = 0; index < tabs.length; index++) {
    promiseList.push(createListEntry(tabs[index].id, index));
  }
  const promisesFinished = Promise.all(promiseList);
  const sortedList = (await promisesFinished).sort((a, b) => {
    return a.vidLength - b.vidLength;
  });
  console.log(sortedList);
  for (let index = 0; index < sortedList.length; index++) {
    await chrome.tabs.move(sortedList[index].tabId, { index: index });
  }
}
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Sort Your Tubes",
    "version": "0.0.0.2",
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Click to sort YouTube videos by video length."
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "popup.js"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "scripting"        
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://www.youtube.com/*"        
    ]
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was helpful, thank you for your great answer!